# Rygel slowing down my Debian system

Tags: debian, performance

Recently I noticed that a process called `rygel` is taking a lot of IO resources every time I am starting something on my home system. What is this process doing and how can I disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`rygel`](https://live.gnome.org/Rygel) is a DLNA / UPnP media server. It has it's own database as well, in one of your home folder's hidden directories, that could be quite big... I found the same thing, with it hogging IO resources on the HD on every log in, so I got into a habit of killing it on every log-in, with:

```
pkill -9 rygel
```

**EDIT:**

To answer your question though, the process is indexing every standard DLNA folder in your home directory, if they exist: ~/Pictures/, ~/Videos/, ~/Music/, and possibly others. All this info will be stored in a database hidden somewhere in your home folder. You can customise these settings in one of the rygel configuration files. See `man rygel.conf` and `man rygel` for more info.

Comment: Is there any way to configure it to have a smaller database, or disable it, or something - so that I don't have to kill it every time?

Comment: I didn't look into what was starting rygel... It wasn't a system service, so didn't have an init script. Perhaps it was started by `~/.xinitrc`? It does have a configuration file, though. Both in `/etc/`, and `~/.rygel.conf` maybe. Also, there's a man page. `man rygel` will tell you all the configuration file locations..